# Azure AD - Sign-in using email as an alternate ID

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory, identity, azure-powershell

I realize this is probably a "noob" question but I am trying to follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-use-email-signin) guide to enable our users to sign in to **Microsoft Azure AD using their email address instead of their UPN**.

**Some background:** Our org uses a UPN scheme that is different from a users email address. Our UPN's follow the format abc12d@organization.com while user's email is firstname.last@organization.com. This enables us to have unique UPN's no matter how big our org scales. I am new to Azure AD but I've managed to integrate most of our 3rd party systems with Azure.

**The problem:** I mapped the user email field as the UPN for one of our services (Apple Business Manager) and now when a user tries to sign in to their Apple ID, it tries to sign them into Azure with firstname.last@organization.com instead of Azure UPN abc12d@organization.com. Because we have not enabled Microsoft's *Sign-in using email as an alternate ID* feature, the sign in window tries to sign them into an account that doesn't exist.

**What I've tried:** I know the simple solution would be to just change the mapping in Apple Business Manager to use the users true UPN from Azure but most of our sign-in's now use the users email so I really don't want to create confusion. I have tried to follow the guide mentioned above, which I assume is referring to using PowerShell in Azure and not your on-prem AD DS service (but it does not specify). Every time I attempt to follow the guide, I get an error message on step 3 in PowerShell that says `Get-AzureADPolicy: The term 'Get-AzureADPolicy' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

I have tried reading though various online forms but am yet to encounter anyone who is encountering this error for this specific use case. No other online documentation has helped me resolve the problem. In my mind, it is probably user error and limited experience with Azure and PowerShell cloud.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am happy to provide more information as needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Get-AzureADPolicy` is under Azure Active Directory PowerShell 2.0-preview.

You need to install the preview release using:

```
Install-module AzureADPreview
```

Don't forget to import it:

```
Import-Module AzureADPreview
```

Note that you cannot install both the preview version and the GA version on the same computer at the same time.

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0-preview#installing-the-azure-ad-module). If it still doesn't work, running `UnInstall-Module AzureAD` before you install preview version may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much! This pushed me in the right direction and I was able to get it setup.